# How to append an single item to other sortable list

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sortables, they're connected and I want to press a button to send an item from `sortable1` to `sortable2`.
It's like showed in this site (https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists), but I just added a button inside the `<li>` to trigger the action to move from one side to another.
I've tried the following, but it just moves all the items from `sortable1` to `sortable2`:

```
$('#btnChange').click(function(){
  $('#sortable1 li').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#sortable2');
  });
});
```

And...

```
$('#btnChange').click(function(){
  $('#sortable1 li').appendTo('#sortable2');
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How does your code know which item is supposed to be moved?   Please create a stack snippet with relevant html and includes.

Comment: By default, the User should Drag and Drop the item from one list to the next. You can program a button to detach an item from one list and then append it to the another. If this is done, you must `refresh` both lists so they can detect the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable1 li button").click(function(event) {
    var self = $(this).parent().detach();
    $("button", self).remove();
    $("#sortable2").append(self);
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1 <button>></button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2 <button>></button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3 <button>></button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4 <button>></button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5 <button>></button></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Please See:

- https://api.jquery.com/detach/
- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

When the User clicks the button, that specific LI is detached from it's parent and appended to the target.